# ¿alguien sabe porque no error tengo en mi endpoint que me lanza un error de System.InvalidOperationException core.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, dotnetcore

Hola llevo unos dias en los cuales trabajando en este endpoint de c# core.net 3.1, pero no e podido avanzar con el por un error que no logro comprender este es el error que me lanza:

```
{
  "ClassName": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "Message": "Unable to resolve type: Sinapsis.NuestraFlota.Api.Controllers.SignatureCheckListController, service name: ",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": {
    "ClassName": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "Message": "Unresolved dependency [Target Type: Sinapsis.NuestraFlota.Api.Controllers.SignatureCheckListController], [Parameter: SignatureCheckListProcessing(Sinapsis.NuestraFlota.Processing.SignatureCheckList.ISignatureCheckList`1[Sinapsis.NuestraFlota.Models.SignatureCheckList.ChecklistSignature])], [Requested dependency: ServiceType:Sinapsis.NuestraFlota.Processing.SignatureCheckList.ISignatureCheckList`1[Sinapsis.NuestraFlota.Models.SignatureCheckList.ChecklistSignature], ServiceName:]",
    "Data": null,
    "InnerException": null,
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": "   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.GetEmitMethodForDependency(Dependency dependency)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitConstructorDependency(IEmitter emitter, Dependency dependency)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitConstructorDependencies(ConstructionInfo constructionInfo, IEmitter emitter, Action`1 decoratorTargetEmitter)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstanceUsingImplementingType(IEmitter emitter, ConstructionInfo constructionInfo, Action`1 decoratorTargetEmitMethod)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstance(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, IEmitter emitter)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDynamicMethodDelegate(Action`1 serviceEmitter)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateInstanceDelegateIndex(Action`1 emitMethod)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitLifetime(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, Action`1 emitMethod, IEmitter emitter)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass147_0.<CreateEmitMethodWrapper>b__0(IEmitter ms)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDynamicMethodDelegate(Action`1 serviceEmitter)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDelegate(Type serviceType, String serviceName, Boolean throwError)",
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "ExceptionMethod": null,
    "HResult": -2146233079,
    "Source": "LightInject",
    "WatsonBuckets": null
  },
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": "   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDelegate(Type serviceType, String serviceName, Boolean throwError)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDefaultDelegate(Type serviceType, Boolean throwError)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.TryGetInstance(Type serviceType)\r\n   at LightInject.Scope.WithThisScope[T](Func`1 function)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": null,
  "HResult": -2146233079,
  "Source": "LightInject",
  "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

en el cual dice Que hay una excepción, pero que no da resultado comprensible, este sería la programación de mi enpoint:

```
namespace Sinapsis.NuestraFlota.Api.Controllers
{

    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SignatureCheckListController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ISignatureCheckList<ChecklistSignature> _processorSignatureCheckList;
        public SignatureCheckListController(ISignatureCheckList<ChecklistSignature> SignatureCheckListProcessing)
            
        {
            _processorSignatureCheckList = SignatureCheckListProcessing ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(SignatureCheckListProcessing));
            
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ChecklistSignature>> Post([FromBody] ChecklistSignature obj)
        {
            // Agrega los elementos de la lista a la base de datos
            //await _context.CheckListsSignature.AddRangeAsync(items);
            //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            var result = await _processorSignatureCheckList.CheckSignature<ChecklistSignature>(obj);
            return result;



        }

       
    }

}
```

esto sería mi código en el cual estoy intentando insertar una estructura de un model a una base de datos la cual contiene esas mismas celdas, este es el model:

```
{
    public class ChecklistSignature
    {
         public string name { get; set; }
         public string rol { get; set; }
         public string idList { get; set; }
         public string nameFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

si alguien sabe por qué me salta este error agradecería la ayuda lindo día

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta ultima parte

> Requested dependency: ServiceType:Sinapsis.NuestraFlota.Processing.SignatureCheckList.ISignatureCheckList`1[Sinapsis.NuestraFlota.Models.SignatureCheckList.ChecklistSignature], ServiceName:]

es la que parece importante para ti. Y veo que usas LightInject, puedes verificar que efectivamente estas ligando tu interfaz ISignatureCheckList a algo.
Comunmente esto es en el startup, y se ve algo como

```
services.AddScoped<ISignatureChecklist>
```

Aqui hay un link que alomejor te puede ayudar con esto

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65336374/system-invalidoperationexception-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-dependenc